# pipelining: finding extra cycles in conditional branching?

Tags: caching

this is an exam question.
A CPU has five stage pipeline.Instruction fetch happens in the first stage of pipeline.
A conditional branch instruction computes target address and evaluates the condition in the
third stage of pipeline . The processor stops fetching new instructions following a conditional branch until the branch outcome is known. A progrma executes 10^9 instructions 
out of which 20% are branches. If each instruction takes one clock cycle to complete then find 
total execution time of the program??
Given CPU frequency 1GHz.

Answer is 1.4 seconds. Plz explain how extra cycle is computed due to branch??

Answer (score 0):

There are total 10^9 instructions but 20% are branch so. the branch instructions are 2*10^8.
branch ins=200000000
loss due to a branch instructions is 2
total cost of a branch ins 3
now the total cost of all instructions is (10^9-2*10^8)*1+(2*10^8*2)/10^9 sec

Comment: only due to waste of 2 instructions on each branch.